# My Apple E-mail is incorrect

Tags: email, apple-id, mobile-mail

I tried going to the AppStore and iTunes, etc. and it said that I have the incorrect Apple email (for the Apple ID) and I tried changing it to my actual email but it pops up as a different email.

Is there anything that I can do to reset it to my actual email?

Answer (score 1):

In iTunes...

Tap Featured at the bottom of the screen.

Scroll to the bottom and tap the account name then Sign out.

Tap Sign in and use the account you want.

Then tap Updates.

source: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3078909?start=0&tstart=0